# Define custom operator and specific application

Tags: operators

I want to define a specific operator that will act in generic functions that depend, say, in the variable `z`. My problem is that I want when a specific function is given as an input, to have specific outcome. For example, I would like to overload `CircleTimes` such that `CircleTimes[f[z],g[z]` will do nothing but if `CircleTimes[f[z],DiracDelta[1-z]]` the output to be `f[1]` and similarly for `CircleTimes[DiracDelta[1-z],f[z]]`. This should hold for any `f[z]`.

Comment: Is `CircleTimes[]` commutative? Is the behavior of `CircleTimes[DiracDelta[1 - z], f[z]]` unique to `DiracDelta[1 - z]`, or should similar behavior be expected for e.g. `DiracDelta[z - 3]`?

Comment: Well if its not a huge trouble (or huge implementation) it would be neat to have it generic but for my needs, `DiracDelta[1-z]` is enough. And yes it is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) (i.e. `/:` and `:=`) to associate a "special rule" to `f` only when it appears within `CircleTimes` with `DiracDelta`:

```
ClearAll[f]
f /: CircleTimes[f[_], DiracDelta[_]] := f[1]
f /: CircleTimes[DiracDelta[_], f[_]] := f[1]
```

You can then see the following:

```
CircleTimes[f[z + 1], DiracDelta[1 + x]]       (* Out: f[1] *)
CircleTimes[DiracDelta[-z], f[whatever]]       (* Out: f[1] *)
```

When a function that is *not* `DiracDelta` is involved, then no simplification is made:

```
CircleTimes[g[z], f[x]]                        (* Out: g[z] ⊗ f[x] *)
CircleTimes[f[z], g[z]]                        (* Out: f[z] ⊗ g[z] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Ok that looks good but this is only for function `f`. I would like it to be for any function `f` that is dependent specifically on variable, say, `z`. That means `CircleTimes[c1 f[z],c2 DiracDelta[1-z]]=c1 c2 f[1]`..

Comment: @hal OK. It would have been much more helpful if you had specified those requirements directly in the original question though, so the question doesn't become a moving target

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had. I stated that it should hold for any `f[z]`.

Comment: @hal Yes, you said for any `f[z]` which here does NOT mean "any function of $z$", but any function *of the form* `f[z]`. We deal with code, not math. Also, note that in your example `CircleTimes[c1 f[z],c2 DiracDelta[1-z]]=c1 c2 f[1]` you are not specifying what `c1` or `c2` should be. Are those numbers? Reals? Perhaps the easiest way is for you to give a few examples of expressions you expect to encounter, carefully definining what each variable means, together with the output you expect. Add those to your question to get better answers.